# Celery: Dump the task log into a log file

Tags: python, logging, celery

Will just ask on how to dump the tasks log into a log file. I tried the following but it did not work:

=== first/celeryconfig.py ===

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
        'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
        'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'first.tasks.add': {
            'level' : 'INFO',
            'filters:' None,
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/home/ubuntu/temp/add.log'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'first.tasks.add': {
            'handlers' : ['first.tasks.add'],
            'level' : 'INFO',
            'propagate' : True,
        },
    }
}
```

=== first/tasks.py ===

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from first.celery import app

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
    logger.info('Adding {0} + {1}'.format(x, y))
    return x + y
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the celery version which you are using?

Comment: it's 3.1.15 (Cipater). Thanks

Comment: What does didn't work mean? Does your log is empty or it produced any error? If there is any error, post the traceback.

Comment: there's no add.log produced